# Erro Unauthorized json php

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou querendo que ao selecionar um município a regional selecione automaticamente mas esse erro tá me fazendo quebrar a muringa. Alguém pode me ajudar? 
A rota esta correta já verifiquei varias vezes.

abaixo o controller

```
public function getCadastro(Request $request)
{
    $v['title'] = 'Cadastro de Escola';
    $v['redes'] = Rede::lists('nome', 'id');
    $v['municipios'] = Municipio::lists('nome','id');
    $v['regionais'] = Regional::lists('nome', 'id');


   return view('auth.cadastro', $v);

}
```

e este a blade

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','route'=>'auth.cadastro']) !!}
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::label('municipio', 'Municipio:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('municipio_id',$municipios,null,['class'=>'form-control ']) !!}
            {!! $errors->first('municipio', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span> ') !!}
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::label('regional', 'Regional:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('regional_id',$regionais,null,['class'=>'form-control ']) !!}
            {!! $errors->first('regional', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span> ') !!}
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: E qual é a aplicação Laravel rodando? Ela demanda de autenticação para acessar o recurso solicitado?

Comment: não é necessário loguin.

Comment: public function getCadastro(Request $request)
    {
        $v['title'] = 'Cadastro de Escola';
        $v['redes'] = Rede::lists('nome', 'id');
        $v['municipios'] = Municipio::lists('nome','id');
        $v['regionais'] = Regional::lists('nome', 'id');


       return view('auth.cadastro', $v);
        
    }      Este é o controller